# Vue.js 3 にてvuetify-material-dashboardのエラーについて

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

[vuetify-material-dashboard](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/vuetify-material-dashboard)　から
テンプレートのダッシュボードを使って見たいですが、下記のエラーが表示されます。

参考ページ
[Vue でダッシュボードの雛形を作る最速の道](https://qiita.com/Satachito/items/3911439e9d9de70a8a64)

以下のエラーの解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけないでしょうか。
お手数ですが、宜しくお願い致します。

```
node --version
v20.11.0
```

```
npm list vue
vuetify-material-dashboard@2.1.0 /Users/test/Downloads/vuetify-material-dashboard-master
├─┬ @vue/cli-plugin-babel@5.0.8
│ └─┬ @vue/babel-preset-app@5.0.8
│   ├─┬ @vue/babel-preset-jsx@1.4.0
│   │ └── vue@2.7.16 deduped
│   └── vue@2.7.16 deduped
├─┬ @vue/test-utils@1.0.0-beta.30
│ └── vue@2.7.16 deduped
├─┬ eslint-config-vuetify@0.4.1
│ └── vue@2.7.16 deduped
├─┬ vee-validate@3.4.15
│ └── vue@2.7.16 deduped
├─┬ vue-cli-plugin-i18n@2.3.2
│ └── vue@2.7.16 deduped
├─┬ vue-world-map@0.1.1
│ └── vue@2.7.16 deduped
├── vue@2.7.16
├─┬ vuetify-loader@1.9.2
│ └── vue@2.7.16 deduped
├─┬ vuetify@2.7.2
│ └── vue@2.7.16 deduped
└─┬ vuex@3.6.2
  └── vue@2.7.16 deduped
```

こちらの手順で行っています。

①

```
npm install
```

②

```
npm audit fix --force
```

③

```
npm run dev
```

③＞最初のメッセージエラー

```
MacBook-Air-2:vuetify-material-dashboard-master test$ npm run dev

> vuetify-material-dashboard@2.1.0 dev
> vue-cli-service serve --open

 INFO  Starting development server...
 ERROR  ValidationError: Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
         - options has an unknown property 'disableHostCheck'. These properties are valid:
           object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'disableHostCheck'. These properties are valid:
   object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }
    at validate (/Users/test/Downloads/vuetify-material-dashboard-master/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:158:11)
    at new Server (/Users/test/Downloads/vuetify-material-dashboard-master/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:270:5)
    at serve (/Users/test/Downloads/vuetify-material-dashboard-master/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js:194:20)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95
```

before vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
  },

  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify'],

  pluginOptions: {
    i18n: {
      locale: 'en',
      fallbackLocale: 'en',
      localeDir: 'locales',
      enableInSFC: false,
    },
  },
}
```

変更 vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify'],
  pluginOptions: {
    i18n: {
      locale: 'en',
      fallbackLocale: 'en',
      localeDir: 'locales',
      enableInSFC: false,
    },
  },
}
```

④変更後、vue.config.js 以下の3つのエラーが表示されます。

```
   ╷
65 │     'md': $grid-gutter / 3,
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss 65:11  @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index.sass 1:9        @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass 2:9                 @import
    stdin 2:9                                                       root stylesheet

Warning: 2 repetitive deprecation warnings omitted.

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($border-radius-root, 2) or calc($border-radius-root / 2)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
14 │     'sm': $border-radius-root / 2,
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss 14:11  @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index.sass 1:9        @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass 2:9                 @import
    stdin 2:9                                                       root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($grid-gutter, 2) or calc($grid-gutter / 2)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
58 │ $container-padding-x: $grid-gutter / 2 !default;
   │                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss 58:23  @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index.sass 1:9        @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass 2:9                 @import
    stdin 2:9                                                       root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($grid-gutter, 12) or calc($grid-gutter / 12)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
63 │     'xs': $grid-gutter / 12,
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss 63:11  @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index.sass 1:9        @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass 2:9                 @import
    stdin 2:9                                                       root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($grid-gutter, 6) or calc($grid-gutter / 6)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
64 │     'sm': $grid-gutter / 6,
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss 64:11  @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index.sass 1:9        @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass 2:9                 @import
    stdin 2:9                                                       root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($grid-gutter, 3) or calc($grid-gutter / 3)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
65 │     'md': $grid-gutter / 3,
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss 65:11  @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index.sass 1:9        @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass 2:9                 @import
    stdin 2:9                                                       root stylesheet

Warning: 2 repetitive deprecation warnings omitted.

Warning: 1 repetitive deprecation warnings omitted.

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($border-radius-root, 2) or calc($border-radius-root / 2)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
14 │     'sm': $border-radius-root / 2,
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss 14:11  @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index.sass 1:9        @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass 2:9                 @import
    stdin 2:9                                                       root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($grid-gutter, 2) or calc($grid-gutter / 2)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
58 │ $container-padding-x: $grid-gutter / 2 !default;
   │                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss 58:23  @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index.sass 1:9        @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass 2:9                 @import
    stdin 2:9                                                       root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($grid-gutter, 12) or calc($grid-gutter / 12)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
63 │     'xs': $grid-gutter / 12,
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss 63:11  @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index.sass 1:9        @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass 2:9                 @import
    stdin 2:9                                                       root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($grid-gutter, 6) or calc($grid-gutter / 6)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
64 │     'sm': $grid-gutter / 6,
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss 64:11  @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index.sass 1:9        @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass 2:9                 @import
    stdin 2:9                                                       root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($grid-gutter, 3) or calc($grid-gutter / 3)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
65 │     'md': $grid-gutter / 3,
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss 65:11  @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index.sass 1:9        @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass 2:9                 @import
    stdin 2:9                                                       root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($border-radius-root, 2) or calc($border-radius-root / 2)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
14 │     'sm': $border-radius-root / 2,
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss 14:11  @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index.sass 1:9        @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass 2:9                 @import
    stdin 2:9                                                       root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($grid-gutter, 2) or calc($grid-gutter / 2)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
58 │ $container-padding-x: $grid-gutter / 2 !default;
   │                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss 58:23  @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index.sass 1:9        @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass 2:9                 @import
    stdin 2:9                                                       root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($grid-gutter, 12) or calc($grid-gutter / 12)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
63 │     'xs': $grid-gutter / 12,
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss 63:11  @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index.sass 1:9        @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass 2:9                 @import
    stdin 2:9                                                       root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($grid-gutter, 6) or calc($grid-gutter / 6)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
64 │     'sm': $grid-gutter / 6,
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss 64:11  @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index.sass 1:9        @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass 2:9                 @import
    stdin 2:9                                                       root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($grid-gutter, 3) or calc($grid-gutter / 3)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
65 │     'md': $grid-gutter / 3,
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss 65:11  @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_index.sass 1:9        @import
    node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass 2:9                 @import
    stdin 2:9                                                       root stylesheet
[51%] building (649/1130 modules)
Warning: 1 repetitive deprecation warnings omitted.

Warning: 1 repetitive deprecation warnings omitted.

Warning: 1 repetitive deprecation warnings omitted.


 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                               22:41:30

[eslint] ESLint is not a constructor

You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
  Error: Child compilation failed:
  [eslint] ESLint is not a constructor
  
  - child-compiler.js:174 
    [vuetify-material-dashboard-master]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:174:18
  
  - Compiler.js:605 finalCallback
    [vuetify-material-dashboard-master]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:605:5
  
  - Compiler.js:640 
    [vuetify-material-dashboard-master]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:640:11
  
  - Compiler.js:1329 
    [vuetify-material-dashboard-master]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1329:17
  
  
  - task_queues:95 process.processTicksAndRejections
    node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5
  

ERROR in [eslint] ESLint is not a constructor

ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  [eslint] ESLint is not a constructor
  
  - child-compiler.js:174 
    [vuetify-material-dashboard-master]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:174:18
  
  - Compiler.js:605 finalCallback
    [vuetify-material-dashboard-master]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:605:5
  
  - Compiler.js:640 
    [vuetify-material-dashboard-master]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:640:11
  
  - Compiler.js:1329 
    [vuetify-material-dashboard-master]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1329:17
  
  
  - task_queues:95 process.processTicksAndRejections
    node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5
  


1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 3 errors
```